# Gerrit mutliple patch sets created after successive pulls

Tags: git, gerrit

Consider the following scenario: 2 users A and B with synchronized local git repositories. Both users HEAD is commit with ID 1 on a develop branch. User a does a commit with ID 2 and pushes it to gerrit. User B does the same thing and pushes his commit with ID 3, which is reviewed and verfied, so it is pushed to the remote repository. Now user A makes a pull --rebase. So his commit with ID 2 is rebased on top of commit ID 3 from user B. Due to rebasing, the commit with ID 1 is getting a new commit ID 4.

And now comes the problem: User A does another push to gerrit, so commit with ID 4, previously 1, is pushed again. The change ID stays the same, because it was only a rebase. This second commit is threated as a new patch set at the gerrit review, although there were no changes made. Consider this happens more than once, then you have several patch sets, all with the same changes! The reviewer has to look through all patch sets, althrough all are the same.

My questions are: Is this really supposed to be the workflow within Gerrit? Or are we doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The user B wouldn't probably rebase his work over and over again.

There are different [Submit Actions](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/project-setup.html#submit_type) available and IIRC except *Fast Forward Only* all will work without rebasing (in case the branch changed).

Furthermore there is also a "Rebase" button in the UI, which rebases the patch and transports the reviews to the new Patch Set so that people don't have to vote again.

Long story short: Just let user B do his work instead of rebasing the whole day.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is something with the rebase as the ID1 should not change. In the end he should have ID1->ID3->ID4, where ID4 is formally known as ID2. If not, then your rebase is wrong.

The recommended workflow is to ALWAYS work in a branch locally. This way you have more control over your merges and you can integrate when you are ready to integrate and merge the other users commit.

```
# User A works in local branch A, user B works in local branch B
ID1->Branch A (ID2)-> Push to refs/for/master
   \-Branch B (ID3)-> Push to refs/for/master
# After ID2 is merged with the master, user B pulls and does a rebase locally
ID1->ID2
     \->Branch B (ID3) Rebase this branch to point to ID2
# After the rebase this is what it should look like
ID1->ID2->Branch B (ID4) Push to refs/for/master again
```

This is the recommended workflow (I think)